# Is it possible for Regex.Match() to return null? (C# .Net framework 3.5?)

Tags: c#, regex, .net-3.5

Is it possible that regex.Match in the (much simplified) code below can ever return null?

```
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
Match m = regex.Match(input);
```

My static analysis tool complains without a null check on m, but I'm thinking it's not actually necessary. It'd be nice to remove the null check so my code coverage is 100% for the method it's contained in.

Comment: You should check if there was a match with `if (m.Success)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) is your friend here:

> *Return Value*
>
> Type: [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> An object that contains information about the match.

Microsoft is telling you that it will only return a `Match` object (not `null`), which means you can rightfully assume this to be true.

There is a chance, according to the docs, that it throws an exception ([`ArgumentNullException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`RegexMatchTimeoutException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexmatchtimeoutexception(v=vs.110).aspx)), though.

What you want to check, is the returned `Match`'s [`Success`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success) property.

Comment: In Framework 3.5 it will not throw a RegexMatchTimeoutException. Thanks, I wanted clarification.

Comment: Good point on v3.5, @ChopperCharles, sorry I missed that tag. Bottom line, if the documentation says something functions a certain way then that is outside of the scope of your unit tests (in my opinion). Theoretically, there is a chance that there's a bug on their end that could return `null`...but, there should be unit tests on their end to prevent that from happening.